# How do I execute a command from a specific directory without actually changing to that directory

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to execute a command like 'git tag -l' inside a directory /home/user/git/app/ but I am actually in /home/user.
How can I do that in bash without changing my working directory?

So NOT:

```
cd /home/user/git/app && git tag -l
```

because that actually changes my working directory and have to do 'cd /home/user' again.

Comment: is cd - so hard to type, another thing to look at is go-tool http://code.google.com/p/go-tool/

Comment: it is inside a script. nothing to do with lazyness

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just bracket the whole thing. That will run it in a subshell which can go to any directory and not affect your 'current working' one. Here's an example.

```
noufal@sanctuary% pwd
/tmp/foo
noufal@sanctuary% (cd ../bar && pwd && ls -a )
/tmp/bar
./  ../
noufal@sanctuary% pwd
/tmp/foo
noufal@sanctuary%
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is another solution: use pushd to change directory, then popd to return:

```
pushd /home/user/git/app && git tag -l; popd
```

Comment: When you want to run a command somewhere else without changing the working directory, `pushd`/`popd` are definitely the way to go.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `&&` instead of a semicolon before the `popd`? Otherwise, you might end up in a third directory.

Comment: The one problem with the `pushd`/`popd` approach is that it can lose information such as the `OLDPWD` environment variable. You are better off not stomping the user's environment and just run in a subshell.

Comment: @D.Shawley: Yes, you are correct.
@Dennis Williamson: I am a little confused, would you please explain?

Comment: Try `pwd; pushd /bin; pushd nonexistent; popd` (where the first `pushd` represents one that you had done earlier and is unrelated to the second one) you'll end up in the directory printed by the `pwd`. Then try `pwd; pushd /bin; pushd nonexistent && popd` you'll end up in `/bin` which is where you started the failed `pushd`. However your version works if the `pushd` succeeds and the `git` fails.

Answer (score 5):

If the command in question is always going to be a git command, you should just use the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` options to tell git what to do! (Or if you're doing this a lot over the course of a script, set the variables GIT_DIR and GIT_WORK_TREE to the appropriate paths)

If this is a general question, I believe Andrzej has a start on the best suggestion: use a subshell. The proper way to start a subshell, though, is to use parentheses, not to use command substitution (unless you actually want to capture the output):

```
( cd $dir && run_command )
```

The other solution, as suggested by Felix and ibread, will of course work, but do be careful - if the command you're executing is perhaps a shell function, then it could also cd, and change the effect of the `cd -` at the end. The safest thing in the general case is to store the current directory in a variable first.

Comment: It is a git command mostly, so it is both. Thanks for the hint on the GIT_DIR!

Comment: This is how all of the scripted git commands work internally (at least in current git) - they inherit the settings for GIT_DIR and GIT_WORK_TREE from the calling git command, and then git commands they subsequently call inherit it from them.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to do something like `(cd /home/user/git/app && git tag -l)`.  This spawns a new shell and executes the commands in the shell without changing your shell.  You can verify this by executing the following:

```
$ echo $OLDPWD
/Users/daveshawley
$ (cd / && ls)
...
$ echo $OLDPWD
/Users/daveshawley
```

Comment: I'd still suggest using `&&` instead of `;`, in case you're using a variable for the directory, so it may not exist, and the command would abort (or worse, mess things up).

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
cd -
```

after everything is done. This command is used to go back to your last working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cd -` after your command

```
cd my/dir1/.test1 && cd - && cd my/dir2/.text2
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function can be added in the *.bashrc*

```
execute_under_directory()
{
    if [ $# -lt 2 ] 
    then
        echo "usage: execute_under_directory <DIRECTORY_PATH> <COMMAND>"
        return 1
    fi

    local current_directory=$(pwd)
    cd $1

    shift
    "$@"

    cd $current_directory
}
```

And by also adding an alias, for example

```
alias eud=execute_under_directory
```

, you can run any command just like this:

```
eud path/to/project git tag -l
```